# Video produced by ReplayKit is constantly skipping frames in Xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, replaykit

I have a very basic video recording project that was working perfectly in Swift, but the same code ported into a blank project in Xamarin is producing a video that is constantly skipping frames every few seconds. The code starts in `ViewDidLoad` and is stopped via a `UIButton` Here is the recording code below:

```
RPScreenRecorder rp = RPScreenRecorder.SharedRecorder;
AVAssetWriter assetWriter;
AVAssetWriterInput videoInput;

public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();
    StartScreenRecording();
}

public void StartScreenRecording()
{
    VideoSettings videoSettings = new VideoSettings();
    NSError wError;
    assetWriter = new AVAssetWriter(videoSettings.OutputUrl, AVFileType.AppleM4A, out wError);
    videoInput = new AVAssetWriterInput(AVMediaType.Video, videoSettings.OutputSettings);

    videoInput.ExpectsMediaDataInRealTime = true;

    assetWriter.AddInput(videoInput);

    if (rp.Available)
    {
        rp.StartCaptureAsync((buffer, sampleType, error) =>
        {
            if (buffer.DataIsReady)
            {

                if (assetWriter.Status == AVAssetWriterStatus.Unknown)
                {

                    assetWriter.StartWriting();

                    assetWriter.StartSessionAtSourceTime(buffer.PresentationTimeStamp);

                }

                if (assetWriter.Status == AVAssetWriterStatus.Failed)
                {
                    return;
                }

                if (sampleType == RPSampleBufferType.Video)
                {
                    if (videoInput.ReadyForMoreMediaData)
                    {
                        videoInput.AppendSampleBuffer(buffer);
                    }
                }

            }

        });
    }

}

public void StopRecording()
{
    rp.StopCapture((error) => {
        if (error == null)
        {
            assetWriter.FinishWriting(() => { });
        }
    });
}
```

And here is what the VideoSettings file looks like:

```
public class VideoSettings
{
    public string VideoFilename => "render";
    public string VideoFilenameExt = "mp4";
    public nfloat Width { get; set; }
    public nfloat Height { get; set; }
    public AVVideoCodec AvCodecKey => AVVideoCodec.H264;

    public NSUrl OutputUrl
    {
        get
        {
            return GetFilename(VideoFilename,VideoFilenameExt);
        }
    }

    private NSUrl GetFilename(string filename, string extension)
    {
        NSError error;
        var docs = new NSFileManager().GetUrl(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomain.User, null, true, out error).ToString() + filename + 1 + "." + extension;
        if (error == null)
        {
            return new NSUrl(docs);
        }
        return null;
    }


    public AVVideoSettingsCompressed OutputSettings
    {
        get
        {
            return new AVVideoSettingsCompressed
            {
                Codec = AvCodecKey,
                Width = Convert.ToInt32(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size.Width),
                Height = Convert.ToInt32(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size.Height)
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have linking turned on for the project?

Comment: I have it on "Link Framework SDKs only"

Comment: I would recommend trying to skip linking specifically for that namespace.  Under IOS Build in Additional mtouch arguments try the following --linkskip=ReplayKit (proper namespaceas required)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the video quality hasn't improved with those arguments

Comment: @spogebob92 I ***assume*** you are testing with release builds and in the release configuration, LLVM is turned on, Thumb-2 is turned off and you are using `Xamarin.iOS 11.10.0.15` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: You need a `try {} finally {}` block in order to help the GC to timely release your sample buffers:

```
try {
    // Do stuff with the buffer.
} finally {
    buffer.Dispose ();
}
```

Long story:

This is because the GC is not fast enough to realize that the CMSampleBuffer needs to be released and you run out of sample buffers, and it is the reason why you kind of see lag because until a new buffer was available it took the snapshot of that actual frame.

Also don't worry about calling `Dispose ()` Xamarin does the right thing so there is no need for additional checks

```
public void Dispose ()
{
    this.Dispose (true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize (this);
}

protected virtual void Dispose (bool disposing)
{
    if (this.invalidate.IsAllocated) {
        this.invalidate.Free ();
    }
    if (this.handle != IntPtr.Zero) {
        CFObject.CFRelease (this.handle);
        this.handle = IntPtr.Zero;
    }
}
```

So your code should look something like this:

```
if (rp.Available)
{
    // TODO: Also note that we are not using the Async version here
    rp.StartCapture((buffer, sampleType, error) =>
    {
        try {
            if (buffer.DataIsReady) {

                if (assetWriter.Status == AVAssetWriterStatus.Unknown) {

                    assetWriter.StartWriting ();

                    assetWriter.StartSessionAtSourceTime (buffer.PresentationTimeStamp);

                }

                if (assetWriter.Status == AVAssetWriterStatus.Failed) {
                    return;
                }

                if (sampleType == RPSampleBufferType.Video) {
                    if (videoInput.ReadyForMoreMediaData) {
                        videoInput.AppendSampleBuffer (buffer);
                    }
                }

            }
        } finally {
            buffer.Dispose ();
        }


    }, null);
}
```

Comment: A little disclaimer, I work for Microsoft and the original issue can be found here: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/3765